# Remove rotation values from linear acceleration sensor in linear acceleration

Tags: android, rotation, translation, sensors

When I rotate and translate my device, linear acceleration give me 3 values:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
   int x=event[0];
   int y=event[1];
   int z=event[2];
}
```

`x` has value from rotating device but I just want the translation value.
How can I remove rotation value from `x`.
Any advice is helpful.

Comment: look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158769/android-acceleration-direction) i guess it's helpful